# How to include readline in webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, readline

I have created nodejs console app and trying to minify it with webpack.

**webpack.config.js** I got:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    externals: {
        fs: "require('fs')",
        readline: "require('readline')",
    },
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'bin'),
        filename: 'bin.js'
    },
    mode: 'development'
};
```

Everything goes ok before I run builded app:

```
readline.js:189
input.on('data', ondata);
      ^
TypeError: input.on is not a function
at new Interface (readline.js:189:11)
at Object.createInterface (readline.js:69:10)
```

What should I do to prevent this error?

Comment: what is you input in `readline.createInterface`? from where are you taking input. Please add MCVE of the code.

Comment: @Aritra, here it is, before I minifyed this everithing worked: `readline.createInterface({input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout, terminal: true});`

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/ can you set `node.process:true`

Comment: @Aritra, I have tryed but nothing changed, :(

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere I found the solution. In the webpack configuration file I must set `target: node` to point the collector what to do with standard external packages (e.g. readline, fs, path, etc.).

Comment: I've been going bananas for an hour trying to figure out why readline wasn't working in my webpack project. This fixed me right up, thank you so much.

Markdown isn't working for me in the comment editor, but to correct one small thing I had to use "target: 'node'" inside my module.exports (Note the single quotes around "node")